# What happens to data on a CI pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, continuous-integration, taurus

I've been asked to create a CI pipeline for a project at my work, I'm creating a load test with JMeter and Taurus so I plan to integrate it with Jenkins to build all the pipeline. I'm just starting on this field and a question that came to my mind is:

What happens to all the data created by the Load Test? does it goes to the deploy phase or it gets deleted once the test is done, should I clean after the tests end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is being kept in the [Jenkins workspace](https://dzone.com/articles/jenkins-02-changing-home-directory) and by default it will be kept in the file system forever.

If you decide to [publish the artifacts](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/) they will be available at Jenkins build dashboard via the web interface.

You might also be interested in [Jenkins Performance Plugin](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/RunTests.html) which allows plotting performance trend charts and conditionally marking builds as unstable or failed depending on pass/fail thresholds

Example configuration can be found in the [How to Run a Taurus Test through Jenkins Pipelines](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-taurus-test-through-jenkins-pipelines) article

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely familiar with your setup but as far as I can see from a quick research, JMeter does the same as every other testing framework and generates HTML reports. Jenkins wont delete them, unless you explicitly delete them (rm file.html) or call cleanWs (clean workspace). If the job is deleted so are the files.

So the test result file should still be present in the deploy phase. You can use a [plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/) to collect the result. Or just archive it. Or do whatever fits your workflow.

There is generally no need to clean it up (you usually configure Jenkins to delete old builds which takes care of that)